# Duplicate value for Guid.NewGuid() in multithread scenario

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, guid

```
class Program
    {
        private static string RequestID;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Thread t1 = new Thread(logs);
                Thread t2 = new Thread(logs);
                Thread t3 = new Thread(logs);
                t1.Start();
                t2.Start();
                t3.Start();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static void logs()
        {
            RequestID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(RequestID);
        }
    }
```

As per my analysis this this happening because `RequestID` field is `static`, but i want to use this `GuId` in static method. the duplicate id are random i.e. if i run the same without threading or on small set of iterations `Guid.NewGuid()` works fine no duplicate.

Comment: Do you want RequestId to be thread-local? Then you may use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Why do you need to store it in a static member? The thing is that three GUIDs are being generated simultaneously and then each thread writes its value to the static field. Then, each thread continues and writes out the value from the (shared) static field which at that time has the value of the thread that wrote the field last. You could make the field thread-static instead but I would generally argue whether you actually need to be static. You could also consider creating a subtype of `Thread` which then can have an _instance_ member if you really need to persist the value for longer.

Comment: @KlausGütter we are using RequestID to uniquely identify each request so, i tried to create a GuId for each request separately but when multiple request comes in n number of threads it produce duplicate value.

Comment: I don't think it is producing duplicate values. Since its multithreaded, and `Console.Writeline` is *significantly more expensive* than generating a `Guid`, It's possible that two threads are calling the `WriteLine` at the same time. at which point, RequestID has the same guid stored. This can be solved with removing the `static` or as suggested `thread-static` field.

If you create a local variable and store the guid and write it to console, do you still get duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

You are not exactly getting duplicates but your code seems to have potential for race conditions between generating the GUID and writing it to console.

This line `RequestID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` may run in two different threads before `Console.WriteLine(RequestID);` is run, causing the console to output the latest GUID twice (or more), thereby appearing to be duplicates.

I'd advise you put a lock around generation and printing, so that the race condition does not occur

```
 private static readonly Object obj = new Object();

 public static void logs()
 { 

    lock(obj){
        RequestID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(RequestID);
    }
 }
```

Comment: While this avoids OP’s observation of duplicate values, I would rather suggest not to store this information statically at all. That way, you can actually execute the threads concurrently without having threads wait on each other.

Comment: The OP's question seems to be showing us placeholder code, so without any further context, it is difficult to assume anything beyond the exact question that the OP asked. Whilst you are right in trying to avoid sharing thread state using a static object being best practice, we'd need to know more before suggesting anything beyond what was asked.